# Writing to a file(fprintf)

Tags: c, file-io, printf

Im trying to add some bindings to ARP table in Linux, in C. Im opening a file with "a" (append, right?) and then trying to write some addresses, but I always get segmentation fault. I believe there is something wrong with `ARP_table[i].IPaddr, ARP_table[i].MACaddr, ARP_table[i].ARPstatus`

```
struct ARP_entry 
{
  char IPaddr[16];
  char MACaddr[18];
  char ARPstatus;
  int timec;
};

static struct ARP_entry ARP_table[ARP_table_vel];

void copyZIS()
{
  int i=0;
  const char filename[] = "/proc/net/arp";
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "a");


  for (i; i< i+j; i++)
  {
     fprintf(file, "%c %c %c", ARP_table[i].IPaddr, ARP_table[i].MACaddr, ARP_table[i].ARPstatus);
  }

}
```

Comment: why don't you fire up an debugger like gdb and run it from there to see what the fault is? What is the scope of `j`? is it a global variable? if > 0 then you have an infinite for-loop

Comment: Did you mean `fprintf(file, "%s %s %s", ...)`?

Comment: Where is j coming from `(i + j)`??

Comment: Are you sure than appending to that file is the correct interface?  Here /proc/net/arp is not writable by anybody, even the root owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking the return value of `fopen`. I am pretty sure **you are not allowed to write to that file**.

```
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "a");
if (NULL == file) {
    perror("fopen");
    /* return / exit */
}
```

Here is `/proc/net/arp` on my system

```
[cnicutar@aiur ~]$ ls -l /proc/net/arp
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun  8 16:29 /proc/net/arp
```

Comment: thats just so true, the same on my system. I could have checked that before. Is there any option how to add sth into that file anyway?

Comment: @shaggy No, there's no way. That is not a real file. My guess is that you're trying to add `ARP` entries - ask a specific question how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one thing, `i<i+j` will always be true, as long as `j` (which you haven't shown) is positive.

Then you're trying to display strings with `%c`, which should be `%s`.

As for the segmentation fault, your `ARP_table` is most likely `0` or garbage, but since you don't actually show how it's created, best of luck with that.

As an aside, I feel I need to point out that that's some horrible looking code. Basic questions like "what are those variables?" should never be asked if you have the full function code and type definition. Instead of being globals they should be passed as parameters from functions better equipped to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `j`?

If `j` is a strict positive constant, you will run into an infinite loop,
because `i` is always smaller then `i + [someting positive]`. This will probably cause the error, because your array has only an finite number of elements.

If `j` is variable and gets negative, you will not run into an infinite loop, but you will produce an `i` bigger then the number of elements in your array `ARP_table`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't write to /proc/net/arp , it's for reading only. (and changing the arp table otherwise is non trivial, you're better off running the external `ip` or `arp` command with proper arguments.
2. Check the return value of fopen, it might fail.
3. Where's ARP_table and j defined ? Perhaps there's something wrong there.
4. The condition `i > i+j` looks weird, are you sure this is the proper condition, and that you shouldn't just stop when `i < j` ?
5. Does ARP_table[i].IPaddr contain something sensible ?
6. `"%c %c %c"` would be wrong. %c prints a single character. It sounds like the two first should be strings, so use "%s %s %c"

Comment: so there is a way how to add sth into arp table, but not the way im trying to do it? i know i can use `arp` or `ip` commands, but i need it to be done in C

Comment: You can run the arp command from C. Other than that, see the source code for the arp command, at http://www.tazenda.demon.co.uk/phil/net-tools/ . There's unfortunatly no real documentation on the C api to do it.